# How to Display Confirmation Box For Automatic Add-on Update?

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I Follow 'http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/automatic-firefox-extension-updates/' to automatic update my add-on xpi file.
But it doesn't update automatically. It updates only when I try to update it manually.
Is there any configuration setting which I need to apply to update.rdf for its automatic update?

I am using my web server to store xpi file for update, & using 'http://' url with update key in install.rdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the updates install when you do a manual update check then updates are working. However, Firefox doesn't check automatically more than once per day, and this check won't happen until several minutes after browser start. Finally, Firefox will never prompt the user on updates (that would be annoying), instead the updates are simply installed when the browser is restarted.

The only exception are extensions where automatic updates have been disabled (wrong browser configuration). To check that you double-click the extension entry in the Add-on Manager. There is an "Automatic Updates" row, normally "Default" should be selected.